# Sending an embed with Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord

I am trying to send an Embed with Discord.js, and it is returning the error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

The code is shown a pastebin
https://hasteb.in/sanunede.js

Answer (score 0):

Error `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` in `message.channel.send(embed)` means, that message.channel returns undefined, so message doesn't contain property channel and message must be wrongly parsed to the function meme

Try using `console.log(message)` right in the beggining of the function if its valid

Could you also show the main code invoking this funciton??